# Finding common rows between two dataframes based on a column using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have two dataframes. I need to extract rows based on common values in column 'a'. However, instead of creating one data frame at the end I want to retain the two data frames.

For example:

```
###Consider the following input
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,1,2,3,4], 'b':['q','r','s','t','u','v'],'c':['a','b','c','d','e','f']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,4,5,6], 'b':['qq','rr','ss','tt'],'c':[1,2,3,4]})
```

The expected output is:

```
###df1:
      a.      b.     c
0.    1.      r.     a
1.    1.      s.     c 
2.    4.      v.     f


###df2:
      a.      b.     c
0.    1.      qq     1
1.    4.      rr     2
```

How can I achieve the following result? Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize it with numpy's [intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

```py
import numpy as np

intersection_arr = np.intersect1d(df1['a'], df2['a'])

df1 = df1.loc[df1['a'].isin(intersection_arr),:]
df2 = df2.loc[df2['a'].isin(intersection_arr),:]
```

More than two dataframes:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

intersection_arr = reduce(np.intersect1d, (df1['a'], df2['a'], df3['a']))

df1 = df1.loc[df1['a'].isin(intersection_arr),:]
df2 = df2.loc[df2['a'].isin(intersection_arr),:]
df3 = df3.loc[df3['a'].isin(intersection_arr),:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df1[df1['a'].isin(df2['a'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2[df2['a'].isin(df1['a'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```